# Vim: How to execute commands stored in a textfile opened in Vim

Tags: vim, gvim

I store, commands found at http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse, in a text file.
If I open this text file in Vim and I want to execute the command where the cursor is actually located I do copy the line with <kbd>Y</kbd>, switching to command mode with <kbd>:</kbd> and <kbd>!</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>
Is there a more "lazy" possibility ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:nmap ,x Y:!<C-R>"<C-H><CR>
```

Then just bang on <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>

The `<C-R>"` pastes the yanked text into the command-line; the `<C-H>` deletes the EOL character which was yanked along with the line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking about shell commands, but if you wanted to do Vim commands, you can read your commands into a register and then run them as macros. Registers used for recording macros and yanking text are the same.

For example:
create text file with

```
:help recording^M
```

(write `^M` by hitting `<C-v>Enter`)

with that file open, type

```
0"ay$
```

then type @a to run that command

---

You can save any macro like this for later.

Record macro:

```
qa[do some commands]q
```

Then put it in a file:

```
"ap
```